# What two kind of decimals you times together to make 1?

Tags: arithmetic

Are there any decimals that times to make 1? I know that 0.25 x 4 = 1 but it's a decimal and a number. I need two decimals. Any ideas? I'm not an expert btw so... thanks

Comment: I'm sutdying for tests.

Answer (score 3):

By decimal, you seem to mean a $0$, then a decimal point, then some numbers, yes? Any such creature is positive and less than $1$. The product of two positive numbers less than $1$ will again be less than $1$.

Now, if you just want two non-whole numbers that multiply to $1$, then $2.5$ and $0.4$ do the job.

Comment: Oh yeah... I didn't think of that. Thanks, lol

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to find the pair of Non Integer Rational Numbers whose product is equal to 1, then the best way is to express it as a fraction and then convert it to a decimal.
Remember

$$\frac{p}{q}\cdot \frac{q}{p} = 1$$

So plug in any $p$ and $q$ to get the desired decimal fractional number.

Example includes but not limited to $\left\{(4,5),(8,5),(5,2)\right\}$ which gives $\left\{(0.8,1.25),(1.6,0.625),(2.5,.4)\right\}$